# Search for an object in the database with a field that can be null

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am trying to retrieve an object from a table by checking these fields against a local copy of them

Bin (Not null), IPN (Not null), Location Id (Not null), Count Date (not null), Lot tag (nullable), and serial number (nullable).

It works fine if I do not include the lot or serial - and it will return the object that HAS a lot tag (In the table you can have many of the same item with different lot tags or serial numbers) but it will never return the ones where the lot tag/serial is null

So my question is how do  I search for these items too? Here is the line of code. It will be null if I include the lot tag/serial stuff at the end. But if I remove it, it will return an item (except I also need it to return the items that contain null in those fields).

```
InventoryPhysicalCount editItem = DatabaseDataContext.InventoryPhysicalCounts.First(i => 
    i.Bin == LocalSelectedItem.Bin && i.IPN == LocalSelectedItem.IPN &&
    i.LocationId == LocalSelectedItem.LocationId &&
    i.CountDate == LocalSelectedItem.CountDate && 
    i.LotTag == LocalSelectedItem.LotTag && 
    i.SerialNumber == LocalSelectedItem.SerialNumber);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all records that match the Not Null fields and have Null fields that are either Null or match the given values:

```
InventoryPhysicalCount editItem =   
    DatabaseDataContext.InventoryPhysicalCounts.First(i => 
        i.Bin == LocalSelectedItem.Bin && i.IPN == LocalSelectedItem.IPN &&
        i.LocationId == LocalSelectedItem.LocationId &&
        i.CountDate == LocalSelectedItem.CountDate && 
        (i.LotTag == null || i.LotTag == LocalSelectedItem.LotTag) && 
        (i.SerialNumber == null || i.SerialNumber == LocalSelectedItem.SerialNumber));
```

If you want the records that match the value (Null if no value is given or the values if a `LocalSelectedItem` value is given):

```
InventoryPhysicalCount editItem =   
    DatabaseDataContext.InventoryPhysicalCounts.First(i => 
        i.Bin == LocalSelectedItem.Bin && i.IPN == LocalSelectedItem.IPN &&
        i.LocationId == LocalSelectedItem.LocationId &&
        i.CountDate == LocalSelectedItem.CountDate && 
        ((i.LotTag == null && LocalSelectedItem.LotTag == null) || i.LotTag == LocalSelectedItem.LotTag) && 
        ((i.SerialNumber == null && LocalSelectedItem.SerialNumber == null) || i.SerialNumber == LocalSelectedItem.SerialNumber));
```

If you want to ignore the `LocalSelectedItem` values if they are Null:

```
InventoryPhysicalCount editItem =   
    DatabaseDataContext.InventoryPhysicalCounts.First(i => 
        i.Bin == LocalSelectedItem.Bin && i.IPN == LocalSelectedItem.IPN &&
        i.LocationId == LocalSelectedItem.LocationId &&
        i.CountDate == LocalSelectedItem.CountDate && 
        (LocalSelectedItem.LogTag == null || i.LotTag == LocalSelectedItem.LotTag) && 
        (LocalSelectedItem.SerialNumber == null || i.SerialNumber == LocalSelectedItem.SerialNumber));
```

Comment: Amazing thank you. I really don't know how I didnt think of that first one its so simple - my brain just stopped working I guess haha. I thought it was something more complicated for some reason. Thank you!

Comment: Also, follow up question if you know. How come it doesn't work like my original answer where LocalSelecteditem.LotTag is null itself? Shouldnt i.LotTag == LocalSelectedItem.LotTag evaluate to true anyways?

Comment: In the database world, two NULL values do not equal each other. That why there is IS NULL and IS NOT NULL. So, for a field that is NULL, field != NULL.

Comment: Ooh okay. Makes sense. Thank you so much!